# Cppcheck not recognizing Command

Tags: c++, cppcheck

I got the following error on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
$ cppcheck --project=compile_commands.json 
cppcheck: error: unrecognized command line option: "--project=compile_commands.json".
```

I already tried reinstalling cppcheck. Does anyone know to what this error is related?

Answer (score 2):

`cppcheck` doesn't support the `--project` option on the version available by default on Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial). The version of `cppcheck` there is `1.72`

If you wish to use the option `--project` then install a newer `cppcheck`.

- It can be installed from the snap store (`sudo snap install cppcheck`).
- It can be installed manually from [cppcheck.net](http://cppcheck.net/#download) - download source, build locally
- You can upgrade to ubuntu 18.04/20.04 and use the version from there.